# Base constructor not called twice when using initialization list

Tags: c++, constructor

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Counter
{
protected:
    unsigned int count;
public:
    Counter() : count(0) {cout << "\nCounter Default Constructor";}
    Counter(int i ) : count (i) {cout << "\nCounter Argument Constructor";}

    unsigned int getData ()
    {
        return count;
    }


    Counter operator ++ () // increment (prefix)
    {
        ++count;
        return Counter(count);
    }
};

class inCounter : public Counter
{
public:
    inCounter() : Counter() { cout << "\ninCounter Default Constructor"; }
    inCounter(int c ) : Counter ( c ) {cout << "\ninCounter Argument Constructor";}

    Counter operator -- ()
    {
        --count;
        return Counter ( count ) ;

    }
};

void main ()
{
    inCounter c1(10); }
```

I was expecting the output to be:

> Counter Argument Constructor
>
> inCounter Argument Constructor
>
> Counter Argument Constructor

But it came out to be

> Counter Argument Constructor
>
> inCounter Argument Constructor

Why is that so?

The reason I was expecting the first output is that during the creation of object `c1`, first the base class constructor is called, hence `"Counter Argument Constructor"` is printed. Then, the derived class constructor is called, hence `"inCounter Argument Constructor"` is printed. But the derived class constructor calls the `Counter` constructor again. So, `"Counter Argument Constructor"` should be printed again.

Comment: Why do you expect `Counter Argument Constructor` to appear twice?

Comment: Why would you expect the Conter class constructor to run twice?

Comment: You should explain why you expect three constructor calls. Otherwise your question is along the lines of "why is 3+3 equal to 6 if I was expecting 7?"

Comment: Because during the creation of object c1, first the base class constructor is called, hence "Counter Argument Constructor" is printed. Then, the derived class constructor is called, hence "inCounter Argument Constructor" is printed. But the derived class constructor calls the Counter constructor again. So, "Counter Argument Constructor" should be printed again..

Comment: @ColorDeColor Put that in the question.

Comment: It's rather bizarre to expect a double-construction!

Answer (score 3):

If a member is initialised via an initialization list, that **replaces** the default initialization that the compiler will perform.

It's not an 'additional' call - as that would mean an object got constructed twice.

Also, you can simplify things by using default parameters in your case. This would allow you to remove some of your unneccessary constructors.

```
inCounter(int c=0) : Counter (c) 
{
  cout << "\ninCounter Argument Constructor";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are confused with the following line in your program,

```
inCounter(int c ) : Counter ( c ) {cout << "\ninCounter Argument Constructor";}
```

Eventhough you have **Counter(c)** in your code, it will not call the constructor twice. Rather it
calls the parameterized version of the base class constructor shown below.

```
Counter(int i ) : count (i) {cout << "\nCounter Argument Constructor";}
```

So the correct output is,

```
Counter Argument Constructor

inCounter Argument Constructor
```